# railsとstripeを使い送金したいができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsとstripeを使い購入時に販売者へ送金するシステムを作りたいがErrorが出てしまいます。
購入機能は実装済みです。

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance) by creating a charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the card number.   You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).):
```

このようなErrorです。

```
  def create
    @product = Post.find(params[:id])
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      source: params[:stripeToken],
    })
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: @product.price,
      description: "商品ID:#{@product.id} 商品名:#{@product.title}",
      currency: "jpy",
    })
    Stripe::Transfer.create(
      amount: 1000,
      currency: 'jpy',
      destination: "acct_1HTeoFHhVt1bl0H3"
    )
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to "/"
  end
```

rails6
postgresSQL
slim使用

なにかわかる方は回答お願いします。

Comment: 「Insufficient funds in Stripe account.」[直訳] Stripeのアカウントに充分な資金がありません。　というエラーなので、プログラムの問題ではないかもしれません。
エラーメッセージには、テストモードでは、、、というような説明が続いていますから、何か参考になる情報かも知れません。Google翻訳などで日本語に直して読み直すと良いと思います。

Comment: 翻訳してみると（Stripeアカウントの資金が不足しています。テストモードでは、カード番号として4000 0000 0000 0077の料金を作成することで、利用可能な残高に資金を追加できます（保留中の残高をバイパスします）。/v1 /ストライプバランスを表示するためのエンドポイントのバランス（詳細については、stripe.com / docs / api＃balanceを参照してください）。
Stripe: : InvalidReqとなりました。詳細も見たのですがどこでどのようにテスト用の資金を使いするかわかりません...。

Comment: お金のやりとりをするサイトのようですので、慎重に調査してください。質問者に必要なのは、プログラムの知識よりも、英語を解読する能力のように思われます。トラブルが起きた際に、Stripeに英語で依頼や抗議ができるようにしておかないと、間違って送金してしまったというような時に困りますよ。(そんな時、StackOverflowは何の役にも立ちませんし)